# Show that $M_{n}=\left(\cfrac{N}{N-1}\right)^n X_n(N-X_n)$ is a martingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expected-value, martingales

Suppose we have a random variable $(X_n)$ such that :

- $X_0=k\in\{1,..,N\}$
- The conditional distribution of $X_{n+1}$ conditioned to $\mathcal F_n=\sigma(X_1,..,X_n)$ follows the binomial distribution with parameters $(N,X_n/N)$

Let $M_{n}=\left(\cfrac{N}{N-1}\right)^n X_n(N-X_n)$.  Prove that $M_n$ is a martingale with respect to $\mathcal F_n$.

**Attempt**: I already proved that $X_n$ is a martingale.

$E(M_{n+1} \, | \, F_n)=E\left( \left(\cfrac{N}{N-1}\right)^{n+1}X_{n+1}(N-X_{n+1}) \, | \, F_n \right)$

I noticed that $X_{n}(N-X_{n})=N*Var(X_{n+1})$

And we know that $E[X_{n+1}\, | \, F_n]=X_n$

But I got stuck there, did I start this wrong? Am I missing a property that I can use?

Comment: How did you show that $\{X_n\}$ is an $\mathcal{F}_n-$martingale? I think you need additional assumptions on $X_n$ than what you have given. Such as what values do $X_n$ take.

Comment: @AndrewShedlock because $X_{n+1}$ follows the binomial distribution $(N,X_n/N)$ when conditioned to $F_n$ you just take the product $N \frac{X_n}{N}=X_n$ by definition of the binomial distribution the expected value is the product of its paramaters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $X_{n+1} \, | \, X_n = x \sim B(N, x/N)$, we have:
$$\begin{align*}
E(X_{n+1} (N - X_{n+1}) \, | \, X_n = x) &= N E(X_{n+1} \, | \, X_n=x) - E(X_{n+1}^2 \, | X_n = x) \\
&= Nx - \left( {x}\left( 1- \frac{x}{N} \right) + x^2 \right) \\
&= (N-1)x\left( 1 - \frac{x}{N} \right)
\end{align*}$$
Where in the second equality we used $E(X^2) = Var(X) + E(X)^2$ and in the last equality we expanded and collected terms. Since $M_n$ is a Markov process, it follows that $$E(X_{n+1} (N - X_{n+1}) \, | \, \mathcal{F}_n) = E(X_{n+1} (N - X_{n+1}) \, | \, X_n) = (N-1)X_n \left( 1 - \frac{X_n}{N} \right)$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
E(M_{n+1} \, | \, \mathcal{F}_n) = \left( \frac{N}{N-1} \right)^{n+1} (N-1) X_n \left( 1 - \frac{X_n}{N} \right) = \left( \frac{N}{N-1} \right)^{n}  X_n \left( N - {X_n} \right) = M_n
\end{align*}$$
Thus $M_n$ is an $\mathcal{F}_n$-martingale.